# Showing a matrix of given form is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an “internet” with n sites, labeled by i = 1, . . . , n. Each site i contains $n_i$
links to some of
the other sites and it is linked to by the pages $L_i$ ⊂ {1, . . . , n}. The page rank $x_i$ of each site i is defined
by:

$$x_i = \sum\limits_{j\in L_i} \frac{x_j}{n_j}$$

Show that a  non-trivial solution ($x \neq 0$) always exists.

A:

I wrote the matrix indices determined by:
$A_{ij} = \ \begin{cases} 
      1 & \text{if } i=j \\
      -\frac{1}{n_j} & \text{if } j \in L_{i}\\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
$

So therefore the leading diagonal will always be 1. Then I wish to turn this form of matrix into an upper-echelon form, as the determinant of the upper-echelon form is equal to the product of the entries along the diagonal. So if any of the diagaonl entries are zero, then the matrix is non-invertible.

So what remains to be proven is that the process of triangularising this matrix cannot produce zero entries along its diagonal:

For this process, I got as far as reasoning that since the elements which are non-zero are of the form $-\frac{1}{n_j}$, where $n_j$ is an integer, then, these elements are $-1 \leq n_j \leq 0$. From here I wanted to make some sort of reasoning to show that when I make the column below the diagonal zero, I will be adding on a positive multiple of a row, since the elements along the leading diagonal will be positive. I'm not quite sure how to phrase this, so I will give an example:

Suppose $$A =  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -1 & 0 \\
-\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Then to make $A_{10}$ equal to zero, I add on 1/2 of row 1 to row 2. The sum of $\frac{1}{2}A_{01} + A_{11}$ can never make zero, and always will be a positive number?

Comment: If the question is to prove that there exists a *nontrivial* solution, then don't you have to prove that the matrix *is not* invertible ?

Comment: Please could you explain that to me? Though I believe you are right, as it explains why det(A) = 0 in the example.

Comment: For a square matrix $A$, the fact that the system $AX=0$ has a nonzero solution is exactly equivalent to the fact that $A$ is not invertible, since it means that its kernel is nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fixed $j$, the entries $A_{ij}$ consist of

- a $1$, when $i=j$;
- $-1/n_i$ once for each element of $L_i$, therefore $n_i$ times;
- $0$ for all other $i$.

So the sum of the entries in each column is zero.  Hence row reducing by adding all rows together gives a zero row, so the determinant is $0$.  This guarantees a non-trivial solution.